# Change variables in QGIS 2.12 using python

Tags: python, qgis-2.12

Now it's possible in QGIS 2.12 to add your own variables, I wonder how I can add new variables or change variables using the Python console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the QgsExpressionContextUtils class (see http://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContextUtils.html).  It has method for adding variables to different scopes, eg global, project, layers, etc.